# How to represent hyperlink in KDoc

Tags: kotlin, href, kdoc

In Javadoc I can represent a hyperlink as `@see <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>`. How can I do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well, actually, *hyperlinks* and `@see` tags are two separate matters in *KDoc*, meaning that `@see` is only limited to API references:

```
/**
 * @see [Object.toString]
 */
class C
```

*Hyperlinks* per se use the regular Markdown syntax (but, unlike *JavaDoc*, can't be mixed with `@see` tags):

```
/**
 * **See Also:** [Google](http://google.com)
 */
class C
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about this. Been using `@see` or hyperlink until your answer